# Ripple Effect doesn't work in listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, xamarin.android, material-design

I have a clickable listview in android and the ripple effect was working when I selected an item, but I change my styles file to add this line for the ripple effect work in buttons

```
<style name="InflorTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
         //other things
         <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/ripple_material_dark</item>
    </style>
```

after I added this line, the ripple effect works in buttons, but doesn't work in listview.

Any suggestions to solve my problem?

Here is my stles file:

```
<resources>
    <style name="InflorTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/ripple_material_dark</item>
    </style>
    <style name="InflorTheme" parent="InflorTheme.Base">
    </style>
    <style name="InflorTheme.Splash" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

here is my styles v-21:

```
<resources>
    <style name="InflorTheme" parent="InflorTheme.Base">
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Here is my listview:

```
<Mvx.MvxListView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listBoletins"
            android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
            android:headerDividersEnabled="true"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:textFilterEnabled="false"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Boletins; ItemClick BoletimClickCommand"
            local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/boletinsitem" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this in your item that you are rendering in adapter.
`android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:clickable="true"` 
in your view

Comment: Where I have to add? in ListView or in layout?

Comment: Hey i have updated my answer. Sorry for the partial answer.

Comment: got the expected result,thanx

Comment: @Tasneem, no it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Why You make such a simple thing so complex.You should use Listview or "appcompat listview" intead of MvxListView.and try to make change in your style for your requirements.

and if U have your own restriction to your custom listview ,then you should try like this.**myview** is your layout view

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

    View myView = findViewById(R.id.myView);
    int[] attrs = new int[]{R.attr.selectableItemBackground};
    TypedArray typedArray = getActivity().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs);
    int backgroundResource = typedArray.getResourceId(0, 0);
    myView.setBackgroundResource(backgroundResource);
}
```

and add this line in your xml file

```
<android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple as

```
<ListView
    ...
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"/>
```

will enable the ripple effect on the list view.